# how to stop Jquery Jail plugin to reload the images once images already loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I used the Jquery Jail plugin to lazy load the images on my Mobile WebApp.

The plugin works fine other than its does not uses cache to keep the images once it loaded .

For example I wanted to stop the the images loading again from the scratch once the images are loaded .

As of now it loads all the time when the page is refreshed .

I am calling the Jail plugin like this

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#outerPage',function(){

            $(function(){
                $('img.lazy').jail({
                    effect: 'fadeIn',
                    speed :1000
                });
            });

});
```

Comment: That's Odd why the Plugging doesn't look in the cache for the images. I can see this could be a problem. Try queryLoader2 instead --- http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/

Comment: Okay bro I will look into this link . I tried understanding the Jail script but its too complicated for me :( .

Comment: @Tasos but Unlikely to Jail QueryLoader2 first loads the images and then the website. What I was trying was to populate the webpage with text and other content and then load the images later .This wasy user get to see the webpage faster

Comment: On the surface that's what it does. But if you use the infinite scrolling for JQM and inject some images when you scroll to the bottom Queryloader becomes a lazy loader. I'm using it myself --- http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/infinite-scrolling/#more-465

Comment: @Tasos so can you guide me how ic an inject the images into this script . Like I need to write the html for image tag with data-src=""  right then get the src of the image and then add it back to the <img> element ?

Comment: Well Queryloader is good if you are preloading a lot of images. You can forgo the plugging all together and use infinite scrolling for JQM as you want to display one image when you scroll to the bottom. I prepare a demo for you.

Comment: @tasos thank you also Although I use the JqueryMobile for the WebApp but the header and footer are generated dynamically using php script . So I think for calculating the height of the window that is shown is also a bit complicated but I think this method would work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61555/discussion-between-vikram-and-tasos).

Comment: @Vikram the code will calculate header/footer even if they are dynamically generated. However, I didn't include extra code for _external_ toolbars. It can be easily added.

Comment: @Omar I am trying to implement it. Whe I am getting confused is `header = $(".ui-header", activePage).hasClass("ui-header-fixed") ? $(".ui-header", activePage).outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-header", activePage).outerHeight(), 
        footer = $(".ui-footer", activePage).hasClass("ui-footer-fixed") ? $(".ui-footer", activePage).outerHeight() - 1 : $(".ui-footer", activePage).outerHeight(),`    here I do not have any element with these class tag you can see in th image . So should I replace these classes with my real header and footer

Comment: Maybe you're not including height(s) of elements outside `.ui-content`. Edit: Yes, those classes are for native jQM toolbars (header/footer).

Comment: just put (-30) here like this, thats how i got it to work -- ((activePage[0].id == "home" && scrolled >= scrollEnd - 30) -- that indicates - 30px from the bottom. if you need more pixels from the bottom then do (-60) --- anyway here is demo for loading the images --- http://jsfiddle.net/ebdp58qm/

Comment: sorry not there, here ($(".ui-footer", activePage).outerHeight() - 1) change the 1 to lets say 50 or 60

Comment: @tasos I do not have theses classes as I am not using the native JQM structure . So I think I need to do RnD to get the right height of the view-port

Comment: If that'ts the case then  it may be a lot simpler to achieve. Can you test this on a mobile and see if it works. It detects when you scrolled to the bottom, not sure if it works on mobiles though ... http://jsfiddle.net/YM5dp/

Comment: @tasos okay I will test it wait Edit . But What am I suppose to see in this its just an empty div . That loads on scroll down

Comment: It wont work if the row of images are within a list. I think that works when the whole page scrolls. -- so i suggest using Iscroll 5 which im using , took a bit of time to learn but got there in the end and use the (myScroll.on('scrollEnd', function() { });) to detect when i scroll to the end. It works like a charm. Its not hard to get the whole thing to work either.

Comment: @tasos I got it . It loads new div when we scroll down .But I canot add all my list view in the Javascript because I am generating the list view in a php for loop . Somthing like this `<?php for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){ ?> <li><img></li><?php } ?>`  so how can I apply this in the `loadMore()` function .

Comment: Also this is one of the examples other pages have different structures . Some places I can apply easily

Comment: I prepared a demo using Iscroll 5 to insert a new row when you scroll to bottom. It doesnt care about headers or footers, just whats in the Wrapper div --- Ignore all the code as i had to insert the Plugging code directly into the fiddle. Go down the bottom of the code to see the code needed to make it work after (///// The ISCROL FUNCTION)  --- http://jsfiddle.net/c6m5gLva/1/

Comment: @tasos What about if I just find all the images inside vieport and replace the data-src tag with src tag . So this way all the other image that are not in view port will not load :) . What do you think will it work ? http://web-profile.com.ua/jquery/dev/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-on-screen/comment-page-1/#comment-1897    using some function like this

Comment: i dont see a problem because Jquery checks the cache first before it goes to the server to get the images. But i suggest loading a whole page or two worth of rows. Doing one row of 3 images at a time is overkill. Something like this -- http://jsfiddle.net/9a43vkpo/  -- ad a loading spinner so the user knows when its finished loading the new rows -- something like this -- http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/ or JQM in built one is also good. the good thing about Isroll it doesnt mess up the scrolling with side Panels if you have any. Its the only reason i use iscroll until JQM sorts that out.

Comment: @Tasos in your example http://jsfiddle.net/9a43vkpo/  the content of `mysearchlist` . I mean the <li> content Those conet in my app is generated dynamically using php so when the page loads all the list elment will be already witten on the DOM. Can you tell me in that case how I can use your method . Due this only I was first letting the List to to be written on the DOm and then checking each list items or image tag that are present inside the viewport . As I do not have more than 10 list view in the page

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61563/discussion-on-question-by-vikram-how-to-stop-jquery-jail-plugin-to-reload-the-im).